# Force download-window to open on file download

Tags: javascript, typescript

is there a way to force the browser through JavaScript/TypeScript to open the download-window. I'd like to open the download-window because most users are downloading directly to the download folder and I'd like to offer the user the possibility to rename the file and to choose the download folder.

I enable the download like this:

```
    const json = JSON.stringify(data);
    const blob = new Blob([json], {type: 'application/json'});
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    const a = document.getElementById('export');
    a.download = 'export.json';
    a.href = url;
```

Comment: please have try .....

Answer (score -1):

Full blogpost for the same : [Download File in Angular Js2 Application](http://pranayamr.blogspot.in/2017/12/download-file-in-angular-js2-application.html)

this two line missing in you code :

```
var url= window.URL.createObjectURL(b);//add this line 
window.open(url);//add this line for download
```

I suggest try like this :

```
  constructor(private http:Http)
  {}

  DownloadFile():void
  {
    this.getFile("http://localhost:1800/api/demo/GetTestFile")
    .subscribe(fileData => 
      {
      let b:any = new Blob([fileData], { type: 'application/zip' });
      var url= window.URL.createObjectURL(b);//add this line 
        window.open(url);//add this line for download 
      }
    );
  }

  public getFile(path: string):Observable<any>{
    let options = new RequestOptions({responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob});
    return this.http.get(path, options)
        .map((response: Response) => <Blob>response.blob())  ;
  }
```

similar answer by me : [Angular JS empty pdf in new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47659449/angular-js-empty-pdf-in-new-window/47659553#47659553)

Comment: why there is -1 ??? it working code and it open window for download .....

Comment: If I try this method, my browser opens a new tab which is automatically closed and nothing is happening. :/

Comment: @Leonzzen - code is also not working for me in my company environment as they blocked popup window and also disabled download...that might be case with you ..i suggest you check browser settings also...code is working for me at home

Comment: I want the "save-as window"/"download window" to open so I'm able to choose where to save my file and also the name

Comment: @Leonzzen - so that is working for me at my home ... please check your browswer setting ...if you check my blog post i given that is full code that you can see ...

Comment: @Leonzzen - can you please provide code on plunker ... i can work on it and try to work it out

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/dhXo2Wuz7EIwOYwGFT4Q?p=info I've tried it like this and the file will be downloaded but I'd like to download it as if you press CRTL + S

Comment: This doesn't force a save as dialog in many situations. For example if the file is of type text/plain or if the browser has been registered to handle the returning file type.